# How do I limit the length of characters in a textbox in MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

I would like to limit a textbox to 10 characters in MVC.

```
<label ID="lbl2" runat="server" Width="20px"></label>
<%=Html.TextBox("polNum") %>    
<label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Width="10px"></label>
```

I know you can set the Max Length property in .net.  How do I do that in MVC with a textbox generated this way?

Comment: Why use an `<asp:Label>` ? That's Webforms. This is MVC, use a `<label>` tag.

Comment: It worked either way so I didnt see it as a problem, but thanks for the heads up, I will put this into practice...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to set some html properties...
something like:

```
<%=Html.TextBox("polNum",null, new {maxlength=10}) %>
```

good luck

Comment: Actually, you don't need this overload.  You can skip the null and go with the two-argument version.

Answer (score 3):

Do it in plain HTML:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("polNum", null, new { @maxlength = "25" }) %>
```

(The `null` parameter is because you don't want a default value...)

Comment: Although not hurting anything, the `@` preceding `maxLength` is not necessary here since it is not a language syntax like `class` is

Answer (score 2):

```
<%=Html.TextBox("polNum", new { maxlength = 10 }) %>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492984.aspx

HtmlHelper uses reflection to examine the anonymous type.  It converts the fields of the type into attributes on the, in this case, TextBox control.  The resulting HTML looks like

```
<Textbox id="polNum" maxlength =10 />
```

You can use the anonymous type to add other relevant attributes, such as

```
new { @class = "MyCssClass", type = "password", value="HurrDurr", 
      textmode="multiline" }
```

Comment: In XHTML all attributes should be lower cased, so maxlength instead of MaxLength

Comment: OH DEAR lemme fix that sorry I caused your webpage to blowed up.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [overload of the TextBox method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505258.aspx) which is getting Html attributes :

```
Html.TextBox( "polNum", "value", new { maxlength="10" } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below html for set max length of TextBox
In Html.TextBox second parameter is value for textbox So, you can pass "" or null

```
   <%=Html.TextBox("polNum", "", new { maxlength = 10 }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telephone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "10" } })

Here i use html.Editor (do not use Textboxfor) For and i am use the Telephone number field in my database. i do not want the user to type more than ten numbers for telephone.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) helps to improve the quality of your response. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.